# Unpair list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell

I have this excercise in Haskell where we have a list of tuples and we need to unpair them and put them into different lists.

Desired outcome:

```
Main> unpair [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
([1,3,5],[2,4,6])
```

My code, but I get some errors:

```
unpair :: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
unpair list = ([a|a<-list.fst], [b|b<-list.snd])
```

errors:

```
Template.hs:8:22:
Couldn't match expected type `b0 -> c0' with actual type `[(a, b)]'
Relevant bindings include
  list :: [(a, b)] (bound at Template.hs:8:8)
  unpair :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b]) (bound at Template.hs:8:1)
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `list'
In the expression: list . fst

Template.hs:8:22:
Couldn't match expected type `[a]'
            with actual type `(b0, b1) -> c0'
Relevant bindings include
  list :: [(a, b)] (bound at Template.hs:8:8)
  unpair :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b]) (bound at Template.hs:8:1)
In the expression: list . fst
In a stmt of a list comprehension: a <- list . fst
In the expression: [a | a <- list . fst]

Template.hs:8:39:
Couldn't match expected type `b2 -> c1' with actual type `[(a, b)]'
Relevant bindings include
  list :: [(a, b)] (bound at Template.hs:8:8)
  unpair :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b]) (bound at Template.hs:8:1)
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `list'
In the expression: list . snd

Template.hs:8:39:
Couldn't match expected type `[b]'
            with actual type `(a0, b2) -> c1'
Relevant bindings include
  list :: [(a, b)] (bound at Template.hs:8:8)
  unpair :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b]) (bound at Template.hs:8:1)
In the expression: list . snd
In a stmt of a list comprehension: b <- list . snd
In the expression: [b | b <- list . snd]
```

The question also states to try to do it with list comprehensions.

Thanks

Comment: Please, please, please include relevant error messages when you ask programming related questions. Never just say "I get some errors". It makes everyone fumble in the dark as to what your error is, and also makes us suspect you did not read the error message yourself.

Comment: Alright sorry, Will include them. But I'm very new to haskell so dont get much out of the error messages

Comment: @Milebril Do you come from an object-oriented language? Remember that function application in Haskell uses prefix notation, instead of the dot syntax used for calling a method on an object (in Java, etc.).

Comment: Yeah im used to programming in Java, etc

Comment: Tuples are odd. List comprehensions are cool. `([ x | (x,y) <- ls], [y | (x,y) <- ls])` where `ls` is your tuple list. More than one list comprehensions is not cool but tuples are odd.

Comment: FYI: `import Data.List (transpose)` then `transpose [ [x,y] | (x,y) <- ls]` where `ls` your tuple list. But the output is a list, not a tuple like the comprehensions before. The comprehension here converts the tuples into lists for a list of lists instead of list of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only slightly hinted to by your error message. The problem you have is that you are mis-using the `.` operator. You might have programmed in an object-oriented language before where `list.fst` calls a function `fst` on the `list` object. This is not the case in Haskell where `.` is an [infix function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator) used to [compose](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition) two functions.

What you really want to do is to pick tuples from your list, and then apply `fst`/`snd` on those tuples one at a time. For example:

```
[fst a | a <- list]
```

You can also use pattern matching and skip `fst`/`snd` altogheter, but it is a matter of opinion if this is better or worse:

```
[a | (a, _) <- list]
```

Comment: Thanks, but quick question, why do we put it like [fst a | a <- list] and not [a | a <- fst list]

Comment: @Milebril I actually explained that in my answer below

Comment: @Milebril if you want to apply a function to every element in a list like you are trying, you can use `map fst list`

Comment: @Milebril `fst` needs a tuple, `list` is not a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost right! You've just got some minor errors:

- In Haskell, you can't do `list.fst` - that is syntactically valid, but the `.` operator doesn't do the same thing in Haskell as it does in other languages. `fst` is a function and should be used as such - try applying it to a value e.g. `fst list`.
- More significantly, you can't apply `fst` or `snd` to a list like `list`; as Haskell is a strongly typed language, these functions must be applied to a single value, not a list. Try moving these functions to the left of the bar e.g. to get all the `fst` values in a list, use `[fst a | a <- list]`, meaning 'for each value `a` in `list`, apply `fst` to `a`'.